# Save e-mail body and its attachments from Thunderbird

Tags: javascript, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I'm trying to save the e-mail body and its attachments from javascript using a custom addin, and I'm not able to do it as described in http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2030903 Do you have any suggestions? Does the e-mail body can be saved into the native EML format? Thank you!

```
alert("Messages selected: " + gFolderDisplay.selectedCount);
let enumerator = gFolderDisplay.selectedMessages;
for each (let msgHdr in fixIterator(enumerator, Ci.nsIMsgDBHdr)) {
    var messageID = msgHdr.messageId;
    alert("MessageID: " + messageID);
    var subject = msgHdr.mime2DecodedSubject;
    alert("Subject: " + subject);
    MsgHdrToMimeMessage(msgHdr, null, function (aMsgHdr, aMimeMsg) {
        try {
            alert("Size of the message: " + aMimeMsg.size);
            alert("Structure of the message:\n" + aMimeMsg.prettyString(true, undefined, true));
            let attachments = aMimeMsg.allUserAttachments || aMimeMsg.allAttachments;
            alert("Number of attachments: " + attachments.length);
            for (let [index, att] in Iterator(attachments))
            {
                alert ("URL: " + att.url  + " Name: " + att.name);
                let ioService = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIIOService);  
                let neckoURL = null;  
                neckoURL = ioService.newURI(att.url, null, null);  
                neckoURL.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIMsgMessageUrl);  
                let uri = neckoURL.uri;  
                let attInfo = new AttachmentInfo(att.contentType, att.url, att.name, uri, att.isExternal);
                attInfo.save();
            }
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    }, true, { examineEncryptedParts: true, });
}
```

[EDIT] The above code does save the attachments but it opens the SaveAs dialog. Can it be done quietly? Does the e-mail body can be saved into the native EML format? Thank you! [/EDIT]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote the example above. You're almost done, and you figured out the hardest parts. Here's what I just did to figure out how to answer your question.

1. I ran an mxr search on AttachmentInfo which turns out to be defined at http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mail/base/content/msgHdrViewOverlay.js#1643
2. Turns out `save` is just a proxy for nsIMessenger::saveAttachment, defined at http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mailnews/base/public/nsIMessenger.idl#81
3. It also turns out that there's a `saveAttachmentToFile` method there! Probably what you need. Reading the definition, it seems like a good candidate http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mailnews/base/src/nsMessenger.cpp#614

You probably need to pass the function an already opened nsIFile (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIFile as there's good reference material there), as well as the URI of the attachment (available as `uri` in your code), the message's uri (probably something along the lines of `msgHdr.folder.getUriForMsg(msgHdr)`), the content type (`att.contentType` here), and a listener implementing `nsIUrlListener` (defined here: http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mailnews/base/public/nsIUrlListener.idl#48, see https://github.com/protz/GMail-Conversation-View/blob/master/modules/message.js#L1492 for a very barebones implementation -- you should probably hook your own functions there to check that everything went fine).

I didn't try this code but I'm pretty confident the guidelines are sound.